# How do I change the number of decimal places iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, calculator

I have a simple calculator app and I want it to be so that if the answer requires no decimal places, there are none, just whole numbers. If the answer was 2, I don't want it to say 2.000000, it should say 2. If it requires one decimal place, it should show to one decimal place for example 12.8 instead of 12.80. How would I do this? Here is my code.
btw, this is from a tutorial at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ihw0cfNOrr4, not my own work.

viewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

interface calcViewController : UIViewController {

float result;
IBOutlet UILabel *calculatorScreen;
int currentOperation;
float currentNumber;

}


-(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)buttonOperationPressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)cancelInput;
-(IBAction)cancelOperation;



@end
```

in the .m

```
#import "calcViewController.h"

@implementation calcViewController



-(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender {


currentNumber = currentNumber *10 + (float)[sender tag];
calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2f", currentNumber];

}

-(IBAction)buttonOperationPressed:(id)sender {
if (currentOperation ==0) result = currentNumber;
else {


switch (currentOperation) {
    case 1:
        result = result + currentNumber;
        break;
    case 2:
        result = result - currentNumber;
        break;
    case 3:
        result = result * currentNumber;
        break;
    case 4:
        result = result / currentNumber;
        break;
    case 5:
       currentOperation = 0;
        break;




}
}
currentNumber = 0;
calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2f", result];
if ([sender tag] ==0) result=0;
currentOperation = [sender tag];

}

-(IBAction)cancelInput {

currentNumber =0;
calculatorScreen.text = @"0";

}


-(IBAction)cancelOperation {



currentNumber = 0;
calculatorScreen.text = @"0";
currentOperation = 0;

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to use NSNumberFormatter to format your result instead of NSString's `-stringWithFormat:`:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:requiredDigits];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
NSString *result = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:currentNumber];
```

Comment: Wherever you need to represent a float as a string with no trailing zeros. My advice would be to allocate and configure the formatter once in your view controller and store it in a property so that you can use it as needed. Then, when you want to display the result of a calculation, just use the last line to create a string that you can display in a label.

Comment: Perfect, OT: how do you guys find such things directly ? I mean, I had the same question. At first point apple guys thought about implementing it. and then you found it out. I am wondering how do you find?

Comment: @jeet.chanchawat 20% experience, 80% knowing that when something seems more difficult than it should be, there's usually an easier way, or several easier ways. Using a formatter gives you the most control, but for the OP's stated requirements `-stringValue` or `-description` do the right thing and are more concise. When you're dealing a class like `NSNumber` that's used by every Mac and iOS app ever written, it's a good guess that tools already exist for displaying a number every way you're likely to need.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is just use **`[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:] stringValue]`**

Example:

```
float someFloatValue;
NSString floatWithoutZeroes = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:someFloatValue] stringValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

If we use `%g` in place of `%f` will truncate all zeros after decimal point.

### For example

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", 1.201000];
```

### Output

```
1.201
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
NSString *result = [@(currentNumber) description];
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This is the code snippet that solved it (looks a lot like Caleb's solution, but that one didn't work for me, so I had to add an extra line):

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
numberFormatter.numberStyle = kCFNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 20;
numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0;

NSNumber *number = [[NSNumber alloc]init];
NSString *numberString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:number];
```

We can use another numberStyle and override its basic appearance, setting desired properties of an NSNumberFormatter.