# Xamarin Numeric only field

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin forms View I have an entry control, to which I have added,

```cs
myEntry.Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric;
```

to make it decimal only.

In Android devices this code will accept only one decimal point at any given time.

However in IOS, it accepts multiple decimal points?? Is there any way I can restrict only one decimal point in IOS too.

Comment: This [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531095/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-decimal-places-ios) might help

Comment: If it works on Android and not on iOS, sounds like a bug to me. Xamarin.Forms is supposed to offer a consistent functionality in all platforms. You might work around this with the answer given below, but ideally you'd also report this to Xamarin to be fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **Xamarin.Forms** **Entry** you have a **TextChanged** event handler that you can tap into when the entry changes.

You are given **both** the **old text string** and also the **new text string** value.

You can then do a **count** on the number of decimal points that are in the **new text string**, check to see if it is **greater than 1**.

If it is, simply set the **Entry.Text** to the **old value** and then you will only ever have one decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

Using the TextChanged event handler you can one of the various TryParse methods. These methods can be given specific cultures and styles also. Example below uses Double's version.

```
private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string newValue = e.NewTextValue;
    double value;
    if (double.TryParse(newValue, out value))
    {
        // Do logic for valid value
    }
    else
    {
        // Do logic for invalid value
    }
}
```